# PHP Doctrine ORM newbie - Valid DSN for dropping database?

Tags: php, orm, doctrine

I'm going through the tutorials for doctrine and liking it so far, however I'm stuck at the point of dropping/regenerating the db schema.

This is the code I am using (pretty much straight from the tutorial)

```
require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '/lib/vendor/doctrine/Doctrine.php');
spl_autoload_register(array('Doctrine', 'autoload'));
$manager = Doctrine_Manager::getInstance();


$manager->setAttribute(Doctrine::ATTR_AUTO_ACCESSOR_OVERRIDE, true);
$manager->setAttribute(Doctrine::ATTR_AUTOLOAD_TABLE_CLASSES, true);   
$dsn = 'mysql:dbname=test;host=127.0.0.1';
$user = 'root';
$password = 'test';

$dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
$conn = Doctrine_Manager::connection($dbh);

$conn->setOption('username', $user);
$conn->setOption('password', $password);

Doctrine::loadModels('models');



Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Doctrine_Connection_Exception' with message
'You must create your Doctrine_Connection by using a valid Doctrine style dsn in order 
to use the create/drop database functionality'
```

Can anyone tell me the correct syntax to use for the DSN, the examples given are a little confusing.

I'm running on localhost through XAMPP.

Any advice appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This dns will work, not to mention that it might be more readable also.
This is the "[Lazy connection](http://www.doctrine-project.org/documentation/manual/1_1/en/introduction-to-connections%3Alazy-database-connecting)" method.

```
// At this point no actual connection to the database is created
$conn = Doctrine_Manager::connection('mysql://username:password@localhost/test');

// The first time the connection is needed, it is instantiated
// This query triggers the connection to be created
$conn->execute('SHOW TABLES');
```

If you want to use the PDO handler beneath, then call it as:

```
$pdo_handler = $conn->getPdh();
```

Answer (score 0):

The [doctrine manual](http://www.doctrine-project.org/documentation/manual/1_1/en/introduction-to-connections) says, e.g.,:

```
phptype://username:password@hostspec/database
```

In your case:

```
mysql://user:pass@127.0.0.1/test
```

You used the PDO variant, which isn't incorrect but not needed.

Answer (score 0):

Doctrine 2:

```
$params = array(
    'driver' => 'pdo_mysql',
    'host' => '127.0.0.1',
    'port' => null,
    'dbname' => 'test',
    'user' => 'root',
    'password' => 'test',
);

$conn = DriverManager::getConnection($params);

// Drop
try {
    $conn->getSchemaManager()->dropDatabase($name);
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    // Could not drop database
}
```

Сorrect me if I made ​​a mistake somewhere